# Timer does not work when button is clicked

Tags: android

I was wondering my code bellow, I can't find the error points. Can anyone explain me, what is the wrong point?

I want to click on button and delay 3s then will Toast will appear.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int timeout = 10000;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Timer is work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                }
            }, timeout);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's Quite easy

Modify your Code Like below :-

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

```
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v)
        {

        int timeout = 10000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ACTIVITY_NAME.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Timer is work",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              }
                });
        }
    }, timeout);
});
```

Comment: your code is work very perfect for me. Thank you so much, I decided to use your code. Again thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Handler` . Timer runs on a different thread. You should update ui on the ui thread. use `runOnUiThread`

```
I want to click on button and delay 3s then will Toast will appear.
```

Use a the below

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              // do something
           }
    }, 3000);

public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)

Added in API level 1
Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Parameters
r   The Runnable that will be executed.
delayMillis The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.
Returns
Returns true if the Runnable was successfully placed in to the message queue. Returns false on failure, usually because the looper processing the message queue is exiting. Note that a result of true does not mean the Runnable will be processed -- if the looper is quit before the delivery time of the message occurs then the message will be dropped.
```

If you want to repeat toast every 3 seconds

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ; 

m_handler = new Handler(); 
m_handlerTask = new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override
public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Timer is work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

 m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 3000); 
 }
 };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To cancel the run use  `m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);`

Using `Timer`

```
Timer _t = new Timer();  
_t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
              {
               public void run() 
               { 

                 //update ui

               }
              });

         }
     }, 1000, 1000 );  // change to 3000
```

Comment: @SopheakVirak use handler postdelayed to run a task with a delay.

Answer (score 1):

`Timer` is runs in the Different thread you can not show `Toast` in the another thread..so Show Toast in the UI thread..
Why are you finishing your activity before showing toast..
change your code like this..

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int timeout = 10000;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Timer is work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                    finish();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }, timeout);
    }
});
```